# Reverse for '<WSGIRequest: GET '/createAgent/'>' not found. '<WSGIRequest: GET '/createAgent/'>' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python-3.x, django-views

```
     ## views.py ##



            from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
            from django.http import HttpResponse
            from crimeapp.login import Designation
            from crimeapp.adminModule import AgentManagForm
            from crimeapp.models import AgentManagement

            def mainPage(request):
                designation=Designation()
                return render(request,'./templates/menu.html',{'form':designation})

            def createAgent(request):
                agntManagement=AgentManagForm()
                return redirect(request,'./templates/agentmanagement.html',{'form':agntManagement})

            def viewAgent(request):
                agentmgnt=AgentManagement(
                    agName=request.GET['agen_name'],
                    agAge=request.GET['agent_age'],
                    dat=request.GET['agent_joining_date'],
                    agid=request.GET['agent_id'],
                    agcity=request.GET['agent_city']
                )
                agentmgnt.save()
                return redirect("../viewAll")

            def viewAll(request):
                agentManag=AgentManagement.objects.all()
                return render(request,'./templates/agentManagement2.html',{'agentManag':agentManag})
            def login(request):
                usr=request.POST['user']
                passw=request.POST['pasword']
                if(usr=='Admin' and passw=='ADMIN'):
                    return redirect("../createAgent")
                elif(usr=='Agent' and passw=='AGENT'):
                    return HttpResponse("logged into agent")
                elif (usr=='Defence Minister' and passw=='DFCM'):
                    return HttpResponse('logged into defence')
                elif(usr=='citizen' and passw=='CITIZEN'):
                    return HttpResponse('logged into citizen')
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('Invalid password or Designation')


        ----------

    ## menu.html ##

        <html>
            <title>Crime Investigation</title>
            <body>
                <table align="center">
                <h1>CRIME INVESTIGATION DETAILS</h1>
                <h3>choose your Field</h3>
                <form action="../login/" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form.as_p }}
                <button>submit</button>
                </form>

                </table>
            </body>
        </html>


        ----------
        ## urls.py ##

        from django.contrib import admin
        from django.urls import path
        from crimeapp import views
        urlpatterns = [
            path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
            path('login/',views.login),
            path('mainPage/',views.mainPage),
            path('createAgent/',views.createAgent),
            path('viewAgent/',views.viewAgent),
            path('viewAll/',views.viewAll),
        ]



    ----------
    ## login.py ##

from django import forms

Choose_Designation=[
    ('Admin','Admin'),
    ('Agent','Agent'),('Defence Minister','Defence Minister'),('citizen','citizen')]

class Designation(forms.Form):
    user=forms.ChoiceField(label="Select your Designation",required=False,choices=Choose_Designation)
    pasword=forms.CharField(label="password",widget=forms.PasswordInput)


----------
## adminModule.py ##
from django import forms
from crimeapp.models import AgentManagement

class AgentManagForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AgentManagement
        fields = "__all__"



----------
```

*I have a form name designation and model class AgentManagement I was trying to create profile for. when logged into from the browser the code flow was good up the def login after getting matched with the password it was not redirecting to createAgent and it was showing the error as 
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch 
 Exception Value:
            Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name

```
        could someone help me in this *
```

Comment: This is often caused by a `{% url ... %}` in the template tag that has as view name, a name that is not a registered view name.

Comment: I have incidated the same template tag name as the view name still I'm seeing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of redirect(request, '') it should be render(request, '') in your create_agent() function. Please accept mark it if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The render function Combines a given template with a given context dictionary and returns an HttpResponse object with that rendered text. You request a page and the render function returns it. The redirect function sends another request to the given url.

Instead of

```
redirect(request,'./templates/agentmanagement.html',{'form':agntManagement})
```

write as

```
render(request,'./templates/agentmanagement.html',{'form':agntManagement})
```